# problem with php_curl.dll load

Tags: php, apache, curl

### related Questions didn't help !

i have a problem loading php_curl.dll under following circumstances:

XAMPP for windows 1.7.2
Apache 2.2.12
PHP 5.3.0
mod_ssl enabled in http.conf
php_curl.dll enabled in php/ext
copied ssleay32.dll and libeay32.dll in system32
checked the extension by php: if (extension_loaded('curl'))-> FALSE !
and all i got in apache errors.log is:
[Sat May 22 15:13:20 2010] [error] an unknown filter was not added: DEFLATE

can you tell me what do i have to do ??!?!?!?

Comment: is curl extension enabled from php.ini file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is unrelated to PHP. It means you are somehow relying on Apache's mod_deflate, but that Apache module is not loaded. Try enabling mod_deflate in `httpd.conf` or commenting out the offending line (search for `DEFLATE` in httpd.conf).

As for the PHP curl extension, you must make sure it's activated in php.ini. Make sure `extension_dir`is set to the directory php_curl.dll is in:

```
extension_dir = "C:/whatever"
```

and then add

```
extension=php_curl.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely Windows is not able to find your DLL.

you should try adding the path to your DLL-s in System Variables

Right click on My Computer -> Properties -> Advanced -> Enviorment Variables -> System Variables

Select Path -> Edit add the line "`;c:\xampp\....\`" without `"` next to other paths, remember `;` as it defines a new PATH system variables

do not remove the entire line just add it next to others

LE: you need to restart your computer